# Reducing size of SVG tick

Tags: css, svg

I have created an SVG animation tick here: https://plnkr.co/edit/5FlA5j8iXO4EPCzxAugs?p=preview

How can i reduce the size of the tick? For example, to half of the size shown?

```css
#check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  -webkit-animation: draw 1.2s infinite ease;
  animation: draw 1.2s infinite ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
-webkit-@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <path id="check" d="M10,30 l30,50 l95,-70" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Without adding a `xmlns` and `viewBox` attribute, displaying this on a browser will be very spotty. I cannot see the `svg`(neither here nor on PLNKR). The size of an SVG can be easily changed by setting its `width` and `height` and you could always try a `transform: scale(.5,.5)` to reduce it's size by half.

Comment: ALSO: For your animation to work on Safari, use `@-webkit-keyframes`, not `-webkit-@keyframes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css `transform: scale(0.5);` to `#check` like this:

> The CSS transform property lets you modify the coordinate space of the
>   CSS visual formatting model. Using it, elements can be translated,
>   rotated, scaled, and skewed. - by [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```css
#check {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  -webkit-animation: draw 1.2s infinite ease;
  animation: draw 1.2s infinite ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <path id="check" d="M10,30 l30,50 l95,-70" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to add the `viewbox` attribute to your svg element so you could properly control the size of your element by simply changing the width and/or the height while keeping its aspect and its internal coordinate system.

Your element has approx.ly a `140 x 95` viewbox so you could write

```
<svg width="50" viewbox="0 0 140 95">
    <path id="check" d="M10,30 l30,50 l95,-70" /> 
</svg>
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ERuQr4NsKfYHT7kebjkR?p=preview